# Translate Entity Permission per Content Type

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I'm using Entity Translation and I have a user role that should be able to translate nodes of type article but no other content types:

User A should see the Tabs "View, Edit and Translate" for a node of type article but not on node of type "company".

Within the permissions there is only allow translation or not at all. How can I do this? Right now I'm hiding the tabs in my page.tpl if the content type is "article" and the user role fits, but that is not the same as revoking the permission.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible unless you write the code yourself or find someone willing to code it.

[This feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/1440658) is now **Closed (won't fix)**